# QoS Intra Process Communication Issue

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am working on developing intra process communication using the realsense camera D435i and trying to run this launch file - https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/blob/ros2-development/realsense2_camera/launch/rs_intra_process_demo_launch.py but I am getting this error in the command prompt -

```
[component_container-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
[component_container-1]   what():  intraprocess communication allowed only with volatile durability
```

I have all the necessary files in the package. As far as I an understand, it has something to do with the QoS settings but I am not able to figure out how and where exactly should the settings be changed. If anybody has experience of solving this issue, please help me, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417267/qos-intra-process-communication-issue/) by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2023-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue by myself, I was trying to pass enable intra process comm parameter to the script from the launch file but the respective cpp file did not have the parameter defined, now the error has gone away.

---

Originally posted by [Robo_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/90798/robo_guy/) with karma: 115 on 2023-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0